# Declare two different struct sizes

Tags: c, struct, typedef

This is on a microcontroller platform, so RAM use is important.

I have a nice little library that I use for circular buffers.  For the circular buffer, I declare a struct typedef:

```
typedef struct buffer {
    uint8_t data[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    uint16_t newest_index;
    uint16_t oldest_index;
    BufferStatus status;
} Buffer;
```

Normally, I only need one of these per application, so defining the `BUFFER_LENGTH` to a particular value is not a big deal, but I have an application that requires two of them... one of relatively short length (32 bytes) and one of relatively long length (256 bytes).

Is there an easy technique that I can use that doesn't involve `malloc()` that would allow me to declare two variables of two different lengths?

The only think that I have come up with thus far is to make the data in the struct a pointer, declare the array when I declare the buffer, and add the buffer length to the Buffer typedef:

```
typedef struct buffer {
    uint8_t dataPtr*;
    uint16_t length;
    uint16_t newest_index;
    uint16_t oldest_index;
    BufferStatus status;
} Buffer;

uint8_t dataBuf1[256]
uint8_t dataBuf2[32]

Buffer buf1, buf2;

buf1.dataPtr = dataBuf1;
buf1.length = 256;

buf2.dataPtr = dataBuf2;
buf2.length = 32;
```

This will work, but is there a better solution?

Comment: declaring the structure requires no extra space, it doesn't take space until you instantiate it. Since you need them both, just declare them both.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Thank you for looking at this.  If I declare `Buffer buf1` and `Buffer buf2`, then my compiler will allocate the full `BUFFER_LENGTH` to each.  This will functionally work, but will use much more RAM than I am interested in.

Comment: Yes, I see this (especially after looking @ the answer from WeatherVan). I was off in my interpretation of the problem

Comment: @KevinDTimm could I add wording to clear up the interpretation?

Comment: No, the question is clear (I was just lazy in reading)

Comment: Another common trick is to make the put the buffer array as the last element of the structure as a 0-length array, then just malloc the whole structure at whatever size needed. Saves the indirection of a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define two structs like this:

```
#define LARGE_BUFFER_LENGTH   256
#define SMALL_BUFFER_LENGTH   32

typedef struct buffer {
    uint16_t buffer_size;
    uint16_t newest_index;
    uint16_t oldest_index;
    BufferStatus status;
    uint8_t data[LARGE_BUFFER_LENGTH];
} Large_Buffer;

typedef struct buffer {
    uint16_t buffer_size;
    uint16_t newest_index;
    uint16_t oldest_index;
    BufferStatus status;
    uint8_t data[SMALL_BUFFER_LENGTH];
} Small_Buffer;
```

with the `data` member moved to the end, and adding a `buffer_size` member. You should be able to share the handler functions, by casting the pointer to the smaller type to make it acceptable to the compiler. C does not care if you apparently overflow an array, and the `buffer_size` field will take care of the implementation difference. You would use `buffer_size` (initialised of course) wherever you previously used `BUFFER_LENGTH`.

Comment: and, if the OP is so worried about space (and the variable is only one of 2 values SMALL_ and LARGE_) the buffer_size could be just a `char`

Comment: @KevinDTimm but OP does not want to use `malloc`.

Comment: or, even better, to save even more space, have a union with elements `data_small[SMALL_BUFFER_LENGTH]` and `data_large[LARGE_BUFFER_LENGTH]`

Comment: no `malloc` needed, set `buffer_size` to the size used and perform all operations based upon that value.

Comment: @KevinDTimm a union will use unnecessary memory in the small case.

Comment: ah, yes - of course. in the case of SMALL data, unnecessary data is running around.

Comment: @WeatherVane Is there a way to use a MACRO to emulate this answer?  This type of solution had struck me, but it is somewhat less maintainable than a single struct definition that I was hoping for.  Thanks!

Comment: @KevinDTimm I misread your very first comment, thinking you meant `data[1]`. If a small buffer only needs 8-bit control fields, then the handler functions cannot be shared.

Comment: @WeatherVane, this is a violation of type aliasing rule.

Comment: @slightlynybbled I don't know, but if you only have one of each buffer for the lifetime of the program, could you define `data[1]` and use `malloc`. I can understand the aversion, but it's not like you would be using it dynamically.

Comment: @SergeyA my last remark would overcome your very valid objection.

Comment: @WeatherVane, which one?

Comment: @SergeyA I can only see one: the violation of type aliasing rule. And my remark about defining `data[1]`. So there would be only one struct type.

Comment: Thank you both.  In that case, it looks like I may want to just declare a data buffer at compile time and - instead of placing the size in the struct - place a length in the struct and a pointer to the each data buffer in the struct instead of the buffer itself.  Objections?

Comment: I added a potential clarification to my last comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane, but this is not what your answer calls for. If you are suggesting `data[1]`, you should have it in your answer (in which case I would suggest `data[]`, btw)

Comment: I appreciate the effort.  I think this gives me the best directon thus far.  Thank you!

Comment: You cannot use the same tag `struct buffer` for two different structs

Comment: @M.M thank you mybad.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want dynamic allocation you may use a definition like:

```
typedef struct buffer {
    uint16_t newest_index;
    uint16_t oldest_index;
    BufferStatus status;
    int length;
    uint8_t data[];
} Buffer;
```

and then two compatible defined types:

```
typedef struct buffer1 {
    uint16_t newest_index;
    uint16_t oldest_index;
    BufferStatus status;
    int length;
    uint8_t data[LENGHT1];
} Buffer1_t;
```

and:

```
typedef struct buffer2 {
    uint16_t newest_index;
    uint16_t oldest_index;
    BufferStatus status;
    int length; // may be useful...
    uint8_t data[LENGHT2];
} Buffer2_t;
```

Then you can use pointers to play with:

```
Buffer *allocate_buffer(int type) {
    if (type==1) {
      return (Buffer *)malloc(sizeof(Buffer1_t));
    } else ...
}
```

If you don't want dynamic allocation you may play with statically pre-allocated such structures.

Comment: The "compatible defined types" are not compatible (in C, structs are only *compatible* if they are exactly the same).  Also you need to use different struct tags (not `struct buffer` for all).

Comment: No rules for *compatible types* (std 6.2.7) and *flexible array members* (6.7.2.1/18) applies. Did I misinterpret them?

Comment: compatibility requirement for structs includes "If one is declared with a tag, the other shall be declared with the same tag.".  (Even having the same list of members is not sufficient).   BTW I think your idea does work, was just commenting on the word 'compatible'.

Comment: You are right Example 6.7.2.1/20 clearly stated it. But I would be surprised if it really happens...